# CRM Application for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for CRM application to manage an IT workshop running Ubuntu. I have a medium size workshop and I am looking for a CRM application I can use to manage jobs, appointments and track work being done by my staff. Does anyone know of an application that will do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try sugar crm it is open source and has a free community edition:
http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/download

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://dolibarr.com Hope it helps
Online Demo https://www.dolibarr.org/onlinedemo.php
Github https://github.com/Dolibarr/dolibarr

About
Dolibarr ERP CRM is a modern software package to manage your company or foundation activity (contacts, suppliers, invoices, orders, stocks, agenda, accounting, ...).It's opensource software (wrote with PHP language) designed for small and medium companies, foundation and freelances. You can freely install, use and distribute it as a standalone a…